# How is the area unit “m²” pronounced?

Tags: abbreviation, terminology

In the sentence below:

> Das Zimmer ist 14 m² groß.

**How the m² is read?**

I know in English you say *square meter*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The superindex ² is pronounced *quadrat*. In combination with meters, you say:

> Quadratmeter (*engl.* square meter[s])

The action to take the square of a quantity is

> quadrieren

There's an irregular power left (in the sense that it has its own name, instead of just saying *hoch **N***), namely three:

> Kubikmeter

There also exists the slightly more technical *[quartisch](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartische_Gleichung)* for the fourth power, e.g.:

> quartisches Potential

In the context of polynomials, the forth power is also *biquadratisch*.

Answer (score 4):

As was already said, the best way — and the only way for room dimensions — to read *m²* would be

> Quadratmeter

However, that doesn’t work that well with all units. Everything that relates to area, i. e. the different metres, and the old imperial units like *Elle* or *Fuß*, will work. For most other units, it’s slightly preferred to say something like

> Beschleunigung misst man in Meter durch Sekunde zum Quadrat.

or shortened informally to

> […] Meter durch Sekunde-Quadrat.

---

This is also the way, variables in mathematical equations are treated. So if your *m²* isn’t the unit for the area of a room, but actually mass squared in some formula, you would say

> *m*-Quadrat.

Comment: Usually, one would say: "Meter pro Quadratsekunde". ›Sekunde-Quadrat‹ is at least awkward if not simply wrong german; so it could be possible in bavaria ^^

Comment: @rhavin I’ve actually never heard *Quadratsekunde* hence my being hesitant to allow *Quadrat-* for units not corresponding to actual distances/areas. On the other hand, I heard *Sekunde-Quadrat* and related *all the time* at school in Bavaria. And why do we always sound awkward? Y__Y

Comment: I have heard both *Quadratsekunde* and *Sekunde-Quadrat* in real life.

Comment: @rhavin: At least in my physics lessons back at school, my teacher would repeatedly point out that reading "m²" as "Quadratsekunde" is wrong, due to what is outlined in this answer, and that the correct reading is "Sekunde hoch zwei" or "Sekunde zum Quadrat".

Comment: If the correct term ›Quadratsekunde‹ would be wrong, then the quite common term ›Quadratmeter‹ would be also wrong; tell your physics teacher that he should have heard of Einstein and that a sekunde and a meter are just different units for different views on spacetime continuum.

Answer (score -3):

In addition to c.p.s answer, some more units:

- m² and m³

  - 14 m² = vierzehn Quatratmeter
  - 3,18 m³ = drei Komma eins acht Kubikmeter
  - 3,18 m³ = drei Komma achtzehn Kubikmeter (only if there are exactly 2 digits after the comma)
- % (technically it's just a pseudo-unit, but as matter of Language it is a unit)

  - 0,5 % = null Komma fünf Prozent
  - 0,5 % = ein halbes Prozent
  - 1,25 % = eins Komma fünfundzwanzig Prozent
  - 1,25 % = ein-einviertel Prozent (only when talking of interest in an economic context, and only if the fraction is a multiple of 1/4 or 1/8)
  - 1,375 % = eins Komma drei sieben fünf Prozent (not: ... *Komma dreihundertfünfundsiebzig* ...)
  - 1,375 % = ein-dreiachtel Prozent (as described above)
- km/h

  - 130 km/h = hundertdreißig ka-em-ha (colloquial and well-understood, but technically wrong because the fact, that the hour is a fraction, is ignored)
  - 130 km/h = hundertdreißig Stundenkilometer (colloquial and well-understood, but technically wrong)
  - 130 km/h = hundertdreißig Kilometer pro Stunde (technically correct, but rarely used)
- €

  - 7,80 € = sieben Komma achtzig Euro (absolutely correct and also well-understood, but the next version is used much more often)
  - 7,80 € = sieben Euro achtzig (only currency-units can replace the word *Komma*)
  - 12,56 €/m² = zwölf Euro sechsundfünfzig pro Quadratmeter
- other squares and cubes

  - 9,81 m/s² = neun Komma einundachtzig Meter pro Sekunden-Quadrat
  - 12.000 kg*m/s² = zwölftausend Kilogramm Meter pro Sekunden-Quadrat
  - 7874 kg/m³ = siebentausendachthundertvierundsiebzig Kilogramm pro Kubikmeter